# ecs: command not found when I try to deploy from local computer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

When I try do deploy from an ec2 it is working fine but, I configured aws credentials and tried to deploy from my pc , using ecs deploy im getting error

```
ecs deploy {rest of the command}
ecs: command not found.
```

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.22.19 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/18.7.0 botocore/1.23.19
```

```
ecs-cli version 1.21.0 (bb0b8f0)
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Did you install [ECS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CLI_installation.html)?

Comment: Okay I dont have ECS CLI! Let me try that.

Comment: ecs-cli version 1.21.0 (bb0b8f0) , and still facing the issue